# Firestore read documents limitation for sorting by distance

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I'm creating an app in React Native that shows restaurants and businesses near you. I started creating it on the Firebase Realtime Database but I'm quite limited there and that's why I decided for Firestore. But currently I have read the terms of payment and now.

My problem is that I always show restaurants only in my area. I have more than 2,000 companies in the database. But I have the order by distance in the FlatList. So every time I load a list, all the 2,000 documents are always retrieved from the database, and overall, the number of document readings and therefore the amount I will pay is increasing very fast. The same applies to loading all restaurants on the map. **Do you know how to do this and always limit only 20 for display but to make the distance sorting work?**

Now I am sorting in code. Is there any alternative for limit read documents? This code reads all more than 2000.

```
const Restaurants = () => {
  const [restaurants, setRestaurants] = useState([]);
  const fetchRestaurants = async () => {
    const querySnapshot = await getDocs(collection(db, "restaurants"));
    querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
      setRestaurants({
          name: doc.data().name,
          lat : doc.data().lat,
          lng : doc.data().lng,
      })
    });
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    fetchRestaurants();
  }, []);
  return (
    <View style={{ marginTop:18 }}>
      <FlatList
        data={restaurants.sort((a,b) => {
          const aDist = Fce.getDistance(+a.lat,+a.lng)
          const bDist = Fce.getDistance(+b.lat,+b.lng)
          return aDist - bDist;
        })}
        keyExtractor={(item)=>item.id}
        renderItem={({ item }) => (
          <View style={{ marginRight:13 }}>
            <Text>Data</Text>
          </View>
        )}
      />
    </View>
  );
}
```

Comment: Please edit the question to show the code you have now and explain in more detail what's not working the way you expect.

Comment: @DougStevenson I'm just wondering if it's possible to restrict data so that I don't have 2000 reads every time. I tried to load part of the code.

Answer (score 0):

1. Can you filters: by distance, category, ...
2. Can you use cursor so that your results will be paged : https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/query-cursors
3. Limit query results to 30: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/order-limit-data

Comment: Thank you. Can you please advise how I can filter the data by distance without loading all the data?

Comment: when registering restaurants store their localisation as longitude, altitude and latitude like this {latitude: 2, longitude: 3, altitude: 89}, then before sorting try to get the user position (lat, long, alt) and to sort you have just to compare the values from user and those from restaurants.

Comment: Yes, I don't have a problem with that. But with each of these sorting, I need to know all the restaurants, whether everything can sort or not? Currently, my sorting is fine, but every time all the data is loaded. When I limit the data, it does not load correctly according to the distance because the restaurants are not limited to that.

Comment: let say you are looking for restaurents 50Km closer to the user, then you can do.

Comment: let distance = 50;
    let user_lat = 20;
    let user_long = 10;
    let max_lat = user_lat+distance; let min_lat = user_lat - distance;
    let max_long = user_long + distance; let min_long = user_long - distance;

    firestore("collections").where("rest_lat", "<=", max_lat).where("rest_lat", ">=", min_lat).where("rest_long", "<=", max_long).where("rest_lat", ">=", min_long)

Answer (score 0):

If you implement geohashing, it *is* possible to get documents in a certain geographical range. This is explained in the Firebase documentation on [implementing geoqueries](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/geoqueries).

This still won't allow you to get the N documents *nearest* to a certain location though. That type of query simply isn't possible on Firestore, as it'd require the database itself to do the distance calculation, which it doesn't support.